# Videos requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: application/x-subtitle-unknown decoder

Tags: plugins, subtitle

When attempting to play certain videos, this message pops up:

> Required plugin could not be found
>
> Videos requires to install plugins to play media files of the following type: application/x-subtitle-unknown decoder

How do I resolve this?

Comment: That did it. I installed VLC from Snaps and it shows the subtitles. Thank you!

Comment: Which subtitle format(s)/codec(s) does the media file contain? How did you install VLC?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to resolve this issue is to install VLC player. VLC contains just about every codec needed to play videos.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

The website can be found at https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html